# flex doesn't support calc in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox, calc

I am attempting to create a layout using Flexbox. In one of these layouts, I want 3 equal width columns. To accomplish this I am using [calc](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp) to set the column width. This is working fine in modern browsers, but of course in IE it doesn't want to work. Here is my code:

```css
.container {
  width:50vw;
  margin:0 auto;
  display:flex;
}
  .container > div {
    flex:1 0 calc(100% / 3);
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Test</div>
  <div>Test</div>
  <div>Test</div>
</div>
```

As I mentioned, this works fine in modern browsers, but in IE the columns just collapse on each other unless I use a specific percentage in place of `calc`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's a known bug.

> IE 10-11 ignore `calc()` functions used in `flex` shorthand declarations.
>
> Since this bug only affects the `flex` shorthand declaration in IE 11, an easy workaround (if you only need to support IE 11) is to always specify each flexibility property individually.
>
> *source: https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-8*

So, in other words, instead of:

```
flex: 1 0 calc(100% / 3)
```

Try:

```
flex-grow: 1;
flex-shrink: 0;
flex-basis: calc(100% / 3);
```

---

Also, consider this: You don't even need the `calc()` function.

If you want three equal width columns, this will do:

```
flex: 1
```

or

```
flex: 1 0 30%
```

or even:

```
flex: 1 0 26%;
```

With `flex-grow: 1` defined in the `flex` shorthand, there's no need for `flex-basis` to be 33.33%.

Since `flex-grow` will consume free space on the line, `flex-basis` only needs to be large enough to enforce a wrap (should it become necessary).

In this case, with `flex-basis: 26%`, there's plenty of space for the margins, borders, padding, etc., but never enough space for a fourth item.